# How to access specific value from mongoose query callback?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, mongoose

First a little introduction to the situation. I have a MongoDB collection filled with documents. I use a schema.statics to query a particular row

```
TweetSchema.statics.maxAndLimit = function(screen_name, cb) {
  this.find({
    'user.screen_name': screen_name
  }).sort({'id_str':1}).select({'id_str':1,'user.statuses_count':1,'user.screen_name':1,'_id':0}).limit(1).exec(cb);
};
```

When the query is finished it calls the callback (cb).

In the callback I want to bind the values to variables so I can use them later. This is what I can't seem to solve:

```
console.log(result) == [{id_str:'12346875',user:{statuses_count:500,screen_name:'username'}}]

console.log(result.id_str) == 'undefined'
```

Same goes for:

```
console.log(result[0].id_str)
```

Why can I not get a specific value? The typeof(result) says 'object'.

**Update per request**
My non-strict schema caused Mongoose to return a non-real javascript object. So for future reference here's the 'schema' I used:

```
var TweetSchema = new Schema({}, {strict: false});
```

I didn't want to define everything as it's a Twitter Timeline object and thus not always the same.

Comment: What does `console.log(result[0])` output?

Comment: {id_str:'12346875',user:{statuses_count:500,screen_name:'username'}}. So without the [].

Comment: Yeah, that is what I expected, however, if this is true, `console.log(result[0].id_str)` should output `'12346875'` for sure. Could you try to log `result[0].user`

Comment: That's what I thought. result[0].user == 'undefined' as well. Is there any black magic in Mongoose or nodeJS that might affect a callback object?

Comment: Not really, the callback of find will always look like this `function(err, result)` where result is an array of the objects matching the query. `err` is `undefinded` I guess?

Comment: I have a "if(err) return err;" line as first line in the callback. This has me stumped for hours now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43680/discussion-between-roland-and-materik)

Comment: Please add your schema to the question since that was the source of the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using an undefined schema, the json output from find can't be handled like a real javascript object. Use toObject() to convert it and you will be able to use it as you would any other object, you can see the difference here:

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({}))
Model.find({user_id: '1234'}, function(err, obj) {   
    console.log(obj[0].user_id)  // undefined                   
    console.log(obj[0].toObject().user_id)  // 1234     
})
```

or:

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: String,
}))
Model.find({user_id: '1234'}, function(err, obj) {                      
    console.log(obj[0].user_id)  // 1234          
    console.log(obj[0].toObject().user_id)  // 1234
})
```

Comment: Any idea how to update document of such type? I am using non-strict mongoose schema and I am trying to update an array in record as `author.toObject().books.push(someObject)` and then `author.save()` but document is not getting updated.

Comment: toObject is just a json dict. its not a model so you can't change it.

Comment: hmmm. How can one modify documents of non-strict mongoose schemas then?

Comment: Fantastic! Solved my problem!